# Android Studio Autocomplete on gradle files

Tags: android-studio, autocomplete, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have added some property `ext` on my **project's** `build.gradle` file as

[image]

But it won't get recognized for autocompletion in my **app's** `build.gradle` file when I try to use `rootProject.ext` as

[image]

Can somebody suggest me workaround for this type of situation.

Comment: I have this working, but am using `project` instead of `rootProject`...